# Copy pieces of data from a .txt into another file for a spreadsheet

Tags: python, export-to-csv

I have a bunch of data in .txt file and I need it in a format that I can use in fusion tables/spreadsheet. I assume that that format would be a csv that I can write into another file that I can then import into a spreadsheet to work with.

The data is in this format with multiple entries separated by a blank line.

```
Start Time
8/18/14, 11:59 AM
Duration
15 min
Start Side
Left
Fed on Both Sides
No

Start Time
8/18/14, 8:59 AM
Duration
13 min
Start Side
Right
Fed on Both Sides
No

(etc.)
```

but I need it ultimately in this format (or whatever i can use to get it into a spreadsheet)

```
StartDate, StartTime, Duration, StartSide, FedOnBothSides
8/18/14, 11:59 AM, 15, Left, No
- ,      -,        -,  -,    -
```

The problems I have come across are:

-I don't need all the info or every line but i'm not sure how to automatically separate them. I don't even know if the way I am going about sorting each line is smart

-I have been getting an error that says that "argument 1 must be string or read-only character buffer, not list" when I use .read() or .readlines() sometimes (although it did work at first). also both of my arguments are .txt files.

-the dates and times are not in set formats with regular lengths (it has 8/4/14, 5:14 AM instead of 08/04/14, 05:14 AM) which I'm not sure how to deal with

this is what I have tried so far

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

def filework():
    script, from_file, to_file = argv

    print "copying from %s to %s" % (from_file, to_file)

    in_file = open(from_file)
    indata = in_file.readlines() #.read() .readline .readlines .read().splitline .xreadlines

    print "the input file is %d bytes long" % len(indata)

    print "does the output file exist? %r" % exists(to_file)
    print "ready, hit RETURN to continue, CTRL-C to abort."
    raw_input()

    #do stuff section----------------BEGIN
    for i in indata:
        if i == "Start Time":
            pass #do something
        elif i== '{date format}':
            pass #do something
        else:
            pass #do something
        #do stuff section----------------END

    out_file = open(to_file, 'w')
    out_file.write(indata)

    print "alright, all done."

    out_file.close()
    in_file.close()



filework()
```

So I'm relatively unversed in scripts like this that have multiple complex parts. Any help and suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Sorry if this is a jumble.

Thanks

Comment: where does `StartDate` come from and how are you deciding what you want and what you don't?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham date and time were on the same line, StartTime, but I need to separate it into two columns in the end so I seperated them into StartDate and StartTime.  
And like I mentioned in the end state, I decided what I need by just taking the useful data which is basically every other line, the date and time value, the duration value, the left or right value, and the yes or no value for both sides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work, although its not exactly optimal, but I'm sure you'll figure out how to make it better! 
What this code basically does is:

1. Get all the lines from the input data
2. Loop through all the lines, and try to recognize different keys (the start time etc)
3. If a keys is recognize, get the line beneath it, and apply a appropriate function to it

   - If a new line is found, add the current entry to a list, so that other entries can be read
4. Write the data to a file

Incase you haven't seen string formatting being done this way before:
`"{0:} {1:}".format(arg0, arg1)`, the `{0:}` is just a way of defining a placeholder for a variable(here: `arg0`), and the 0 just defines which arguments to use.

Find out more here:

- [Python .format docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)
- [Python OrderedDict docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

If you are using a version of python < 2.7, you might have to install a other version of ordereddicts by using `pip install ordereddict`. If that doesn't work, just change `data = OrderedDict()` to `data = {}`, and it should work. But then the output will look somewhat different each time it is generated, but it will still be correct.

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists
# since we want to have a somewhat standardized format
# and dicts are unordered by default
try:
    from collections import OrderedDict
except ImportError:
    # python 2.6 or earlier, use backport
    from ordereddict import OrderedDict

def get_time_and_date(time):
    date, time = time.split(",")
    time, time_indic = time.split()

    date = pad_time(date)
    time = "{0:} {1:}".format(pad_time(time), time_indic)

    return time, date
"""
   Make all the time values look the same, ex turn 5:30 AM into 05:30 AM
"""
def pad_time(time):
    # if its time
    if ":" in time:
        separator = ":"
    # if its a date
    else:
        separator = "/"

    time = time.split(separator)
    for index, num in enumerate(time):
        if len(num) < 2:
            time[index] = "0" + time[index]

    return separator.join(time)

def filework():
    from_file, to_file = argv[1:]
    data = OrderedDict() 

    print "copying from %s to %s" % (from_file, to_file)
    # by using open(...) the file closes automatically
    with open(from_file, "r") as inputfile:
        indata = inputfile.readlines()
        entries = []

        print "the input file is %d bytes long" % len(indata)
        print "does the output file exist? %r" % exists(to_file)
        print "ready, hit RETURN to continue, CTRL-C to abort."
        raw_input()

        for line_num in xrange(len(indata)):
            # make the entire string lowercase to be more flexible,
            # and then remove whitespace
            line_lowered = indata[line_num].lower().strip()

            if "start time" == line_lowered:
                time, date = get_time_and_date(indata[line_num+1].strip())
                data["StartTime"] = time
                data["StartDate"] = date
            elif "duration" == line_lowered:
                duration = indata[line_num+1].strip().split()
                # only keep the amount of minutes
                data["Duration"] = duration[0]
            elif "start side" == line_lowered:
                data["StartSide"] = indata[line_num+1].strip()
            elif "fed on both sides" == line_lowered:
                data["FedOnBothSides"] = indata[line_num+1].strip()
            elif line_lowered == "":
                # if a blank line is found, prepare for reading a new entry
                entries.append(data)
                data = OrderedDict()

        entries.append(data)

    # create the outfile if it does not exist
    with open(to_file, "w+") as outfile:
        headers = entries[0].keys()
        outfile.write(", ".join(headers) + "\n")
        for entry in entries:
            outfile.write(", ".join(entry.values()) + "\n")

filework()
```

Comment: sorry to do this to you, but how do I install OrderedDict correctly?
I keep getting "cannot import name OrderedDict" even though I thought I installed it. 
once I get it I will try out your suggestion.  I do know about formats, although basically and I probably forgot about them.

Comment: Oh! You might be using a older version of python. I've changed the answer to provide a fix for that :) If none of it works, just change `data = OrderedDict()` to `data = {}` and it should work.

Comment: Thanks! Firstly you made me realize I had python 2.6.6 installed (I thought I had 2.7), so I installed 2.7 and now it does exactly what I wanted, except it stopped after making the header and one entry (and a third blank line). the entries are separated by blank lines. could that screw it up and make it stop? I'm sorry if I didn't mention that. I will edit to show more than one entry.
Thanks again for the code so far!

Comment: No problem! Sorry, I didn't see that at first. I've updated the code, so it should work now.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much for the work and helping me through this. It does exactly what I needed and even skips some random day breaks in there. I have some similar files with different data but I hope to be able to work from what you gave me on my own. You earned this answer.